# Uncertainty relation and Energy-Position interference

Tags: quantum-mechanics, heisenberg-uncertainty-principle

How would you prove that the simultaneous measurements of position and energy are not subject to interference?
I was thinking in calculate the commutation relation between $x$ and $H$ (Because $\Delta E=\Delta H$), but I realized that $[H,x]\neq0$, so I tried to use a more general expression for the Uncertainty Principle that says that if $H_1$ and $H_2$ are Hermitian operators then $\Delta H_1 \Delta H_2\geq\frac{1}{2}|\langle [H_1,H_2]\rangle|$, but again, $[H,x]\neq0$. Can you suggest me a way to do this? Thanks.

Comment: Why do you expect they wouldn't be subject to interference? You're right, $x$ and $H$ generally don't commute, meaning they can't be simultaneously measured.

Comment: What do you *exactly* mean by interference?

Comment: @Burzum It means that between $E$ and $x$ there is no interference of measurements, i.e. $[E,x]=0$ (or?) $[H,x]=0$. That's what I understand.

Comment: @MichaelBrown Actually I thought that as the momentum $p_y$ and $x$ are not subject to interference, i.e. $p_y$ and $x$ are not complementary operators ($[p_y,x]=0$), then in analogy $E$ and $x$ "should" not  be complementary operators. But, in fact I have no reasons to expect that. Actually this is an exercise of the book "A course in Statistical Thermodynamics" by Kestin & Dorfman.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're right to use the general form of the Uncertainty Principle, namely:
$$ \Delta H_1 \Delta H_2\geq\frac{1}{2}|\langle [H_1,H_2]\rangle|. $$
However, note that in the right hand side you have the *expectation value* of the commutator, so even if $[H,x] \neq 0$ it can still be that $\langle [H,x] \rangle = 0$. If this is the case then you can simultaneously measure position and energy.

For example, if you have a simple one-dimensional Hamiltonian with a potential:
$$ H = \frac{\hat{p}^2}{2 m} + V(x), $$
then you can easily show that
$$ [H,x] = -\frac{i \hbar}{m} \hat{p}.$$
Now you just have to check whether your system happens to be in a quantum state for which the expectation value of the momentum vanishes, i.e. $\langle \hat{p} \rangle = 0$.

Comment: I have a doubt. Is it correct to use $H$ instead of $E$? Because I'm looking for a statement between energy and position.

Comment: In Quantum mechanics each measurable quantity has a Hermitian operator associated with it. The operator associated with the energy $E$, is the Hamiltonian $H$. This means any question you have about measurements of the energy, will be answered by performing calculations on the operator $H$. In this case you're asking about the uncertainty of $E$, so you need to use $H$ in the above formula of the uncertainty principle.

Comment: You are right. So, the answer is there is no interference between the simultaneous measurements of position and energy of a system only if the potential $V(x)$ is symmetric. Because in that case $\psi$ is symmetric or asymmetric, then $\langle p\rangle=\frac{\hbar}{i}\int\psi^{*}\partial_{x}\psi dx=0$. Right?

Comment: That's almost right. First of all, even if the potential is symmetric, you still need the system to be in an _energy eigenstate_. Only the eigenstates are guaranteed to be symmetric or antisymmetric. Secondly, it's not true that simultaneous measurement is possible _only_ if the potential is symmetric. There might be other cases in which you get $\langle [H,x] \rangle=0$. All you can say is that this is _one_ case where it is possible.