# Energy $E_n$ for eigenstates $n$ and position probabilistic distribution

Tags: quantum-mechanics, heisenberg-uncertainty-principle, commutator

Energy and position operator does not commute. [Uncertainty relation and Energy-Position interference](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/51922/uncertainty-relation-and-energy-position-interference)

So how come "For a particle in a box with given states $n$," and we obtained the $E_n$ for exact and it's probabilistic distribution  $f(x)=\psi(x)^*\psi(x)$ at the same time?

Comment: Have you tried calculating $\sigma_x\sigma_p$ for a given state $n$?

Comment: Why do you think there is a conflict? Probability distribution is not a measurement.

Comment: @BillN because in the case of infinite well,  changes in $x$ at most $L$, but $E$ was exact and $\Delta E\Delta X=0$.

Comment: Sorry, mistake, in the above stationary case, $<p>=0$, so it's still followed uncertainty principle, just it vanished and holds for all functions here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Expanding the comments:

Measuring the position means saying $x=x_0$. Having a probability density means that tehre is a **probability** of finding the particle there, and it is probable because it is not certain.

(Unless your probability distribution is a Dirac Delta, which won't happen).

If you knew the position, you wouldn't need any probability.

Comment: In the case of infinite well, changes in $x$ at most $L$, whatever the equation was to be, it's finite, but $E$ was exact and $\Delta E\Delta X=0$.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand your comment. $E$ can be defined, but position is not.

Comment: Once the states $n$ was defined, then $E=E_n$ was set, and the $\psi_n(x)$ was defined. Thus $\Delta E_n=0$ and $\Delta X_n=finite$ and $\Delta E_n \Delta X_n=0$.

Comment: Sorry, mistake, in the above stationary case, $<p>=0$, so it's still followed uncertainty principle, just it vanished and holds for all functions here.

Comment: Yes, that's true. I was about to say that after your comments, but I see you've found the answer by yourself. Good job.